# Form is not submitted and Invalid Token in PHP

Tags: php, forms, token

When you click the `Login` submit button, it only shows up "Invalid Token" because the ***token*** given was not recognized by the system. But however, if I click the `Register` submit button, the form is getting submitted and processed.

Form codes:

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="Password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="remember">
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="on"/> Remember Me
    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="login_token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>" />
  <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<hr>
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo sanitize(Input::get('username')); ?>" autocomplete="off" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Choose a Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label for="password_again">Enter your Password Again</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again" />
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo sanitize(Input::get('name')); ?>"/>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="rgstr_tkn" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>" />
      <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register"/>
</form>
```

PHP code to be processed when the form is submitted:

```
if (isset($_POST["login"])){
        if(Token::check(Input::get('login_token'))) {
            echo "Login!";
            echo Input::get('login_token');
        } else {
            echo 'invalid token';
        }
}

if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
        if(Token::check(Input::get('rgstr_tkn'))) {
            echo "Register!";
            echo Input::get('rgstr_tkn');
        }
}
```

`Token` Class:

```
class Token {

  # Generate a token, and put it into the session/token_name
  public static function generate() {
      return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), md5(uniqid()));
  }

  # Check if the token exists
  public static function check($token) {
      $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

      if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
          Session::delete($tokenName);
          return true;
      }

      return false;
  }

}
```

`Input` Class:

```
class Input {

    # Check if the POST or GET request is submitted
    public static function exists($type = 'post') {
        switch($type) {
            case 'post':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
                break;
            case 'get':
                return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
                break;
        }
    }

    # Get an item from the posted or get field
    public static function get($item) {
        if(isset($_POST[$item])) {
            return $_POST[$item];
        } else if(isset($_GET[$item])) {
            return $_GET[$item];
        }

        return '';
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the html source code to verify there is a value in `value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>"`. Have you tried echoing out `Session::get($tokenName)` and `$token` to see what they contain, and why they don't match?

Comment: They both have values and they are both different. I've tried to use single token for both of them but now the register button is not submitting. I've tried to echo out the `token` (which is: `echo Config::get('session/token_name');`) and it only displays *token*.

Comment: can you include your config

Comment: `Sessin:exists()` ? how can you know the token prior to it being passed in if you haven't stored it anywhere?

Comment: My [configuration file](http://pastebin.com/9EWvpmuW).

Comment: @KDOT I use my `exists()` function to check if that $_SESSION exists, and returns a bool (true or false)

Comment: can you show your Session class also

Comment: My [session class](http://pastebin.com/RrE0AHBY),

Comment: seems no problem to me, check if you `session_start();` maybe you haven't `start` the session in your

Comment: Everytime I include my config, there is a `session_start()`

Comment: can you `print_r($_SESSION);` and see the result if your session actually exist in your array, also try to `echo Input::get('login_token);` see it's result

Comment: The token is actually there: (example) `Array ( [token] => 4fd0f4763a244fcb567c33db24bb76b6 )` when you `print_r` it, and when I submitted the register button, it actually matches.

Comment: I mean you hit login the what's the `Array()` look like?

Comment: When I hit the login, it just re-generate a new token.

Comment: I see so that's the problem

Comment: A while ago, I put a `echo Input::get('rgstr_tkn');` in PHP Register script when the token is validated. When you click the register button now, the generated token is the same as `Input::get('rgstr_tkn')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you go back again to that page it generate a new token again
that's why it returns "Invalid token" to solve that

In your

```
public static function generate() {

}
```

you check first if you already have generated your specified session token before creating it

```
public static function generate() {
    $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');
    // if session is already generate then just return it instead of generating new one
    if (Session::exists($tokenName)) {    
        return Session::get($tokenName);
    }
    // else create this session_token
    return Session::put($tokenName, md5(uniqid()));
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `public static function generate() { $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name'); if (Session::exists($tokenName)) {    
         return Session::get($tokenName);
     } return Session::put($tokenName), md5(uniqid())); }`

Comment: @astronomicalXoom I see the error change it to `return Session::put($tokenName, md5(uniqid()));` it's just because of `)` after `$tokenName`

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer :) Well, sorry for bothering you :( I'm only 13 years old and starting in OOP and Classes Hahahaha

Comment: I want, but I can't :( I only have 3 rep :(

Comment: @astronomicalXoom okay good luck to your programming course :)